# Jest test coverage output contains no data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, code-coverage

I am unit testing in React using Jest. When I run `npm test` the test cases pass, but the coverage code does not contain any data:

[image]

How can I see the code coverage data?

**My Component is:**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';

export default class HeaderCreate extends Component {

  render() {

    const { name, description, closeRightSection } = this.props;

    return (

      <div className="header">
        <h1 className="header-text" title={name} data-testid="header">{name}</h1>
        <p data-testid= "description-para">{description}</p>

        <Tooltip title="Close Section">
          <div className="icon-close">
            <i className="material-icons" onClick={() => closeRightSection()} data-testid="id">close</i>
          </div>
        </Tooltip>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Unit Test Case**

```js
import React from 'react'
import { render , fireEvent} from "@testing-library/react";

import HeaderCreate from '../components/createHeader';


test("render header correctly", () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<HeaderCreate name="My Name is Test"></CreateHeader>);
    expect(getByTestId('header').textContent).toBe('My Name is Test')
});

test("render Description Paragraph correctly", () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<HeaderCreate description="Hi I am Description box"></CreateHeader>);
    expect(getByTestId('description-para').textContent).toBe('Hi I am Description box')
});

test("render close tooltip correctly", () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<HeaderCreate closeRightSection=""></CreateHeader>);
    expect(getByTestId('id')).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: What command are you using to execute tests?

Comment: I've tried npm test, npm run test -- --watch, npm run test -- --coverage, npm test --coverageReporters="text-summary"

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

`npm run test --coverage --watchAll=false`

It's very likely a jest bug as mentioned [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6888#issuecomment-486331179).